# Error: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am using IBA IoT Data Simulator and I got this error when I create a session connecting AWS IoT Core.

> *Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined*

Can someone please help me?
I have attached a few other screenshots below.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrOkk.png)
[Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngvO0.png)
[Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1OGi.png)
[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuLYS.png)

Comment: _"Can someone please help me?"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like the property hasn't been initialised

Comment: 3 days and no help. This is usual. For immediate success have a look at our AWS MQTT Lab. https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws